# How to create insert procedure with input parameters in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

How can I create an INSERT procedure in MySQL using phpMyAdmin.  How can I view my procedure in PhpMyAdmin?

The query is:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_db
(
    uname varchar(30),
    pword varchar(30),
    email varchar(30),
    mobile varchar(30)
)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO wfc_user 
        (username, password, email, mobile)    
    VALUES
        (uname, pword, email, mobile);                                                                
END;
//                                   
delimiter ;
```

Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is using `;` before declaring it to be your delimiter again.  When you declare `DELIMITER \\`, you are 'un-setting' the delimiter away from `;`.  This means you cannot use the semicolon as a delimiter again, until you declare `DELIMITER ;`

Try editing your code thusly:

```
END//
```

instead of

```
END;
```